# Create campaign, mails and schedule the send to subscribers lists with FuelSDK C#

Tags: fuel-sdk, c#

I'm trying to schedule the sent of some mails with the FuelSDK (C#) in ExactTarget, but the documentation is really scarse and I'm not even sure how to begin.
Basically what I have is a structure like the following:

```
Campaign: It has a given date.
 |- First Mail Data: Subject, HTML
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 9 AM
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 10 AM
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 11 AM
 |   ...
 |- Second Mail Data:  Subject, HTML
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 9 AM
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 10 AM
 |   |- List of subscribers to send at 11 AM
 |   ...
 ...
```

So, basically I need to create a campaign, add mails to it, and send each mail to a different subscribers lists at differents hours. I don't know if it's important, but different mails to schedule might be for different Business Units.
Researching the FuelSDK demo and examples, I think I have to do something like this:

```
Create campaign
Foreach mail data
    Create email
    Create email asset with previous email
    Add email asset to campaign
    Foreach subscribers list
        Create subscriber list
        Foreach subscriber
            Add subscriber to list
        Create Email Send Definition
        Associate Email Send Definition to email and list
        Schedule Email Send Definition to the corresponding hour
```

That last part is where I'm not sure if it's ok. Every example I've found is a basic CRUD operation, rarely interacting with other structures. I'm not even sure if those are the correct structures to use, as I haven't been able to find too much documentation on ExactTarget itself.
After all this my question would be: Is the previous workflow ok? is it using the correct structures to achieve what I want?
If possible, please share some working example, it might give me a better idea than the simple ones I've found.